# Adding Contact Form 7 to Slider Evolution

Tags: wordpress, slider

Taking about Wordpress, is is possible to add a shortcode of Contact Form 7 plugin at a slide of Slider Evolution Slider?
If yes, how ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you try it yourself first?

Comment: I've did, there is no option to include html code.

Comment: I'm guessing no then, but emailing the creator of it and they might be able to help

Answer (score 1):

Yes is is possible there a real fast way around this but further tinkering may be needed

Add a new layer and paste in the shortcode for the form

Above it where it says `style` just edit this so no styling is available for that layer.

This should work :)